# c++ PE injecting additional functionality

Tags: c++, winapi

For example I have very simple C++ main function

```
int main ()
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) Sleep(10);
    return 0;
}
```

So this exe shuts down after 10 seconds from start. 
Now the question: 
Is there a way to JOIN(concatenate) two PE-applications? 
I am trying to do a program C++ which will unite two apps into a new one. For example: 
Ill run my program with parameter to app:

```
My_app.exe %windir% / calc.exe
```

Exe Wrapper
General description
Exe wrapper is a command line utility that can compile and output a “launcher” exe that
works just like the input exe with a few additional features. The wrapper must be command
line based on takes three input variables:
1. Any windows executable file
2. An expiry datetime
3. URL to server instructions and “download exe”
Example command:
wrapper.exe “input_exe.exe” “20150528
15:00:00”
“http://pemainin.
com/launch_askar.php?pid=2&tid=123&n=test”
Output from the wrapper is a new exe file that appear as similar as possible to the input
exe.
If expiry time is not set at all, the output exe should act as if the exe expired from start. The
output exe should act as follows

Comment: Under the right conditions and with enough relevant information, yes there are ways to do it.

Comment: That's not really concatenation. That sounds more like running the two programs in parallel. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: What is a PE program?  One that works with Physical Education?

Comment: PortableExecutable (exe)  i need to add extra function written in C++ into existing PE

Comment: What you seem to want to do (based on the last two paragraphs) is possible (if involved), but not quite in the way you are suggesting. It's a bit involved. For future reference, you should tell people the problem you're trying to solve. Not give them the somewhat outlandish solution you came up with and ask them how to implement it.

Comment: I am trying to solve, but due to lack of knowledge I am asking help here from community. Any docs will be appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like what you are looking for is a `stub` that gets executed before main application in order to check for the expiration.

Comment: I am going to have to decline to offer any more details. I had assumed you were trying to implement some kind of time-limited trial wrapper, but the edit you just made to your question leaves me with an uneasy feeling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to build is called a "binder". You can achieve the effect you want by having the wrapper "join" two PE files, the `stub` and the `decoy`. The `stub` will implement the main features you outlined (downloading from the link, timeouts e.t.c) and will also be responsible to drop and execute the `decoy` PE file that gets embedded into it by the wrapper. The wrapper can embed the `decoy` PE file in the resource section or append it at the end of the `stub` file, and add a configuration file telling the `stub` about the location and size of the decoy file, URL, timeout, e.t.c into the resource section. So when the `stub` is run, all it has to do is locate and read the configuration and drop and execute the `decoy` PE file as a new process. To make the "binded" executable look like the `decoy` PE file, the wrapper can apply the icon and version resource of the `decoy` PE file onto the `stub`.

[Here](http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/38765-srb-a-better-binder/) is my implementation of a binder with a source code.

Comment: an other nice example. Thank you. Right now I am figuring out your project

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is not feasible.  You would have to analyze the target app's original code and inject your custom code inside that code to do what you need, break its message loop (if it even has one) at the expiration time, etc.  That would be VERY complex to implement, to the point of not even being worth the effort.

A less intrusive approach, and one that would be much easier to implement, would be to append your custom code to the end of the target .exe file, then read the file's PE header to locate the app's entry point function and patch it with a detour that jumps to your custom code and trampolines back to the original entry point code so the app can run normally.  Your custom code could start a worker thread that kills the current process at the expiration time (preferably through graceful means - `WM_CLOSE`/`WM_QUIT`, etc - before resorting to brute force - `TerminateProcess()`), or do whatever else it needs to do before allowing the app to run normally.

Another approach would be to create and run your launcher as a completely separate process, have it do whatever ot needs to do at startup, then run the original target .exe file normally and kill it at the expiration time.  If you want to merge the two .exe files into a single .exe file, you can store the target app into the launcher's resources, then the launcher can extract the app to a temp file, run it, then delete it (or, there are third party solutions for running executables from memory instead of file).  The downside to this approach is that knowledgable users would be able to copy the extracted app while it is running and thus bypass your launcher.

Comment: Yeah, That I was looking for, Remy. Could you describe for a bit from this moment: "You can store the target app into the launcher's resources, then the launcher can extract the app to a temp file, run it, then delete it (or, there are third party solutions for running executables from memory instead of file)"

So exctracting original exe into TEMP dir will be fine!

Comment: for e.x. a calc-new.exe will check the Time conditions, and will unpack from itself to tempdir the calc.exe and run it!

Comment: Create a launcher .exe with a custom resource that is initially blank. Code the launcher so that when it is run, it can [find and load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648006.aspx) the resource, [access its data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648047.aspx), save it to a temp file, and [run it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx)...

Comment: ... your merge utility can then copy the launcher .exe to the desired filename and [update the custom resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648004.aspx) with the raw data of the target .exe.

Comment: do you have skype? Ill need only 5-10 minutes for detailed instructions if you are able to help for a little bit. You dont need to code all of it. Just I need clear understanding. Are you elibigle to do it for me?

Comment: If you read the articles I linked to in my previous comments, and read the documentation for the API functions mentioned, and spend a few minutes searching around, there is plenty of information and code examples readily available.